# C# Want to know is there any enum type that repeats it's value only in the limit

Tags: c#, while-loop, enums

Sorry for my stupid question, I haven't been programming for 7 years and forgot almost everything.

I would like to make a system that can express musical notes,
for example I created the following enum,

```
public enum Notes { C = 0, D, E, F, G, A, B };
Notes N = Notes.C;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(N);
    N++;
}
```

In this code, once the Note's N reaches Note.B, the value doesn't go back to C.
How can I force the value to go back to Note.C?

Your answer would help me a lot.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just an `enum`. You'd likely need to implement a value type with custom operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the remainder operator `%` to wrap your number back:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(N);
    N++;
    // you'd have to do some conversions here as N is not a numeric type
    N = (Notes)((int)N % 7);
}
```

You can also replace the hard-coded magic number `7` with

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Notes)).Length
```

---

EDIT:

I just realised that you were looking for a *type* that does this wrapping around behaviour. Well, a regular enum can't do this. You need to write a custom `struct`, which is essentially a wrapper for an `int`. Just to give you an idea of what this would look like:

```
struct Notes {
    private int intValue;
    private int IntValue {
        get => intValue;
        set {
            intValue = value % 7;
        }
    }

    private Notes(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public static Notes operator ++(Notes note) {
        Notes newNote = note;
        newNote.IntValue++;
        return newNote;
    }

    public static Notes operator --(Notes note) {
        Notes newNote = note;
        newNote.IntValue--;
        return newNote;
    }

    public static Notes C => new Notes(0);
    // all the other notes here...

    public override string ToString() => intValue switch {
        0 => "C",
        1 => "D",
        2 => "E",
        3 => "F",
        4 => "G",
        5 => "A",
        6 => "B",
        _ => intValue.ToString() // or throw an exception
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice answer by Sweeper, but if you want something a little more readable (IMHO) you could do something like;

```
while (true)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Notes), note))
        note = Notes.C;
    Console.WriteLine(note);
    note++;
}
```

Comment: it's a pity that I can't accept more than 1 answer! but thank you very much for the great help.:)